# How to customize FACEBOOK dialogs?

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

Hi guys Ive seen on many apps , that they have customized theyre request/feed dialog, to give it their own design. Does anyone know how can i customize my requests dialog or simply use "a code" to send requests like Zyngas games have?
added photos

[image: this is customize request dialog]http://born2star.com/sssss.jpg
[image]

Im using fb.ui('apprequests') which brings the blue facebook dialog,
Thanks ahead

Comment: A sample screenshot could help even more.

Comment: *Edited, I want to customize my invites, do you know if its possible to developers who are not Zynga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the standard dialog to send app requests. They can't be sent 'by code' without launching the dialog since for security reasons the user needs to approve each request action.  The dialog can't be tailor-made like in the images you show using the public API. There appears to be a private API to tailor the request dialog design for top developers.

Comment: yes im also creating a game in actionscript, the question is , what is the logic for sending invites without using FB.ui(this is also the method in actionscript sdk for Facebook)?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I understand your question better now. I've updated my answer.